# Google Cloud Compute Engine cannot deploy

Tags: deployment, google-compute-engine

Hello I try to deploy the hello world compute engine test project to my asp instance.

When I try to push it I just get the error "Failed to deploy"

> msbuild.exe
>   "D:\getting-started-dotnet\aspnet\1-hello-world\1-hello-world.csproj"
>   /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:WebPublish
>   /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True
>   /p:publishUrl="C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\hgy2katd.oce" Failed
>   to publish project 1-hello-world.

Does anyone have an idea where I can find a more detailed error message or what could cause the problem?

I followed this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/hello-world

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

seems like the problem was that multiple msbuild.exe were used. I reinstalled my pc and everything worked fine afterwards